# Identify a player in a game with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm doing a project which consists in creating a game of the goose-like (with a quiz aspect) and I've some troubles to identify a player when he comes in the game.

I want to do something like, a playerNumber which is increment when a player come.

I've tried something like this but the problem is that when a player comes the variable "joueur" return to 0.

```
var joueur = 0;
    if (typeof numJoueur == 'undefined')
    {
        numJoueur = joueur;
        joueur++;
        var str = "Je suis le joueur " + numJoueur;
    }
```

Do you have some solutions/propositions to overtake the problem ? :)

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm French (as shown in my code ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `joueur` variable declared inside the scope of the route, like so:

```
function newplayerroute(req, res, next) {
    var joueur = 0;
    if (typeof numJoueur == 'undefined')
    /* ... */
}
```

If it is, then that variable gets reset every time this route/function is called. You'll need to declare it in a higher scope:

```
var joueur = 0;
function newplayerroute(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof numJoueur == 'undefined')
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was doing this inside the scope but in a route, like that :

exports.deplacement = function(req,res)
{
var joueur = 0;
// ...

But when I do your method, the variable numJoueur stays at 0 :o 
I think my "if" is also a little bit false. 
Maybe I should use a req.session.numJoueur instead of numJoueur ?

Comment: Yes, numJoueur seems like it should be attached to the client session.